# Where is the Javascript Console/window?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, console

I'm looking for "Javascript Console/window" where code is evaluated and printed back within VSCode and can't find it. My Udemy Prof just starts testing on it. I'm wondering if it's an extension I need to download, or if I'm just overlooking it? Is Console only found in older versions of VSC?

[image]

Comment: That appears to be outside of vscode, to the left of the sidebar. I've never seen an extension in that place.

Comment: Maybe they are using the electron developer tools? It might look like that. They're meant for debugging vscode itself, though, not for trying to test snippet, run your own code, or even learn the language.

Comment: You might want to ask your prof, not us :-)

Comment: When you say "printed back within VSCode", are you talking about console logs? More specifically, what do you mean by "printed back"? What would be printed?

Answer (score -1):

Browser side JavaScript, the JavaScript that is used to edit html documents, does not run on a console app/window. It runs on a browser. Nodejs, On the other hand, runs inside of a console app. Since you are using JavaScript with Html, I will explain how you can view the results of your code that way. If you haven't already, make sure all of your files are in one folder. Open the folder. Right click on the Html file (in your case index.html), and go to open with. You should see an option that says open with Google Chrome (or whatever browser you choose to use). If you are using Google Chrome, it will have an inspect element option. Inspect element has useful development tools such as a console, a network tracker, and sources. The console will tell you the errors that you need to know.